# Contextual Menu Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, macos, shortcut-menu

Is it possible to create a keyboard shortcut for a contextual menu item and if so, how? I'm not sure if this functionality was available in Lion, but if it wasn't, maybe it is in Mountain Lion.

Comment: Most contextual menu items have corresponding shortcuts in the menubar. Which app are you looking to add shortcuts to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set shortcuts for *some* context shortcuts, specifically anything that's a [service](http://www.macworld.com/article/1163996/how_to_use_services_in_mac_os_x.html). Most app-specific context menu items aren't services (although some, such as services to modify a file in a particular app are), so they can't be assigned shortcuts. So it depends which items you want a shortcut for, but it's doable.

To add a shortcut for a service, open **Keyboard Preferences**, click the **Keyboard Shortcuts** tab, and select **Services** in the left pane. Then look for the context menu item you want in the right pane, click it and you'll get an option to set a shortcut.